# Show multiple images inside a repeater control in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working inside a project which is designed in N Tire application.
Inside the project,
I have a repeater control in my page.
I have a anchor tag & inside that i call the image. The code is as follows..

```
<a id="ancher" runat="server" rel="example_group" title="">
<asp:Image ID="imgvideo" runat="server" width="90" height="80" border="1" />
</a>
```

Inside the DAL I call from the database.

Inside the database I have 15 columns which contain a primary key & a foreign key, 10 images column , current Date,video & etc.
All the 10 images are called from a single id.

when i call these images from the code behind then it shows only 1 images which is 10th position inside the database. it take the last image and shows that image only.

Code inside the Repeater as follows..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DAL.DAL_UploadImgVideo obj = new DAL_UploadImgVideo();
dt = obj.ImgVideoFetchDetails(ID);
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       for (int i = 2; i < dt.Columns.Count - 3; i++)
          {
            Image M1 = new Image();
            M1 = ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgvideo"));
            string Cname = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
            string FImg = dt.Rows[0][Cname].ToString();
            M1.ImageUrl = "JO_Images/UpdImgVideo/" + FImg.ToString();
          }
    }
```

Inside the loop it goes threw & shows only the last image because it calls from a single Id of database.

So any one suggest me how can I change the code & get all the 10 images inside my repeater control from a single id of database.

Comment: You are finding the same control and rewriting the imageurl

Comment: I have to call the <a> id or what? Karthik

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383874/creating-a-query-string-when-clicking-on-image-asp-net-c check this out

Comment: R u getting all the images in dt???

Answer (score 0):

I think you may put a Literal into your Repeater instead of the Image control.

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrImage" runat="server">
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DAL.DAL_UploadImgVideo obj = new DAL_UploadImgVideo();
dt = obj.ImgVideoFetchDetails(ID);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var imgFormat = "<image src='JO_Images/UpdImgVideo/{0}' />";
    var imgStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 2; i < dt.Columns.Count - 3; i++)
    {
        string Cname = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
        string FImg = dt.Rows[0][Cname].ToString();
        imgStr.Append(string.Format(imgFormat, Fimg));
    }
    var ltrImg = ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrImage"));
    ltrImg.Text = imgStr.ToString();
}
```